# Combinatorics lock puzzle

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> 11 people in a certain company have access to a safe. The company
> owner wants any group of six people out of the 11 to open the safe,
> But no five-person group can open the safe itself. To achieve this
> goal he decided to put more than one lock on The safe, and give each
> person keys only to some of the locks.
>
> How many locks he has to put on
> the safe and how many keys each person will have to achieve his goal
> (the company owner wants to reduce the number as much as possible The
> locks, and as much as possible reduce the number of keys each person
> receives)?

Any ideas how to approach this question?

Comment: One immediate constraint is that the number of locks has to be $6$ or more. If there are only 5 locks, you can distribute the 5 keys for those locks among at most 5 people, and hence those 5 people can, as a group, open the safe.

Comment: I would assume that in order to open the safe, the six persons must open all of the locks. But that is merely a guess about the author's intent, because the wording of the problem does not imply this. In reality, two locks could be mechanically linked so that opening either one is sufficient to open the safe. We could also conceive of a lock with six keyholes that can be unlocked by any combination of six of $11$ different keys, but only if all six are in the lock. So that's one lock and $11$ keys, but I would bet the author meant to exclude that mechanism.